# No; not any; not a;

Tags: determiners, quantifiers

Good morning, people. I know there are some related posts, but they don't answer my many questions. All ELL and other forum links are **purple**. Believe me, hahaha.

---

1 - In questions/negative questions, can **ANY** follow a singular noun?

> **Q:** Do you have a pen to lend me?
> **A:** No, I don't have any pen/pens.

p.S.: The doubt arose because we know that "ANY" is not **commonly** used with singular count nouns. I don't know if the [exception](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/is-any-or-are-any/#singular-count-nouns) applies in this case.

---

2 - Is it okay to drop "any" and leave just **not** alone?

> **Q:** Don't you have pens?

*That sounds pretty general to me.*

> **Q:** Don't you have any pens?

*It sounds like **"Any kind of."***

---

3 - Are **NO** and **NOT ANY** "identical", meaning **0**? Does Using **NO** turn the sentence more emphatic?

> A: I don't have any bad intentions.

*This doesn't sound like **"any kind of"** to me, as in the previous example. But it sounds like **"zero/0"***

> B: I have no bad intentions.

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This would be better as three separate questions. 1 - no. 2 - both are okay. Other possibilities include "Didn't you bring pens?" or "Didn't you bring any pens?" 3 - yes, they are identical in meaning and the mean zero. Not any is more emphatic.

Comment: Don't get too committed to ideas about different choices of phrasing being more or less emphatic. On average, *I **don't** have **any** idea* is probably more emphatic than *I have **no** idea*, but it's a fairly meaningless distinction. And to be honest, I'm inclined to think *I have no siblings* might actually tend to be *more* emphatic than *I don't have any siblings* - if only because the shorter first version is more succinctly and starkly bleak.

Comment: No, the exception doesn't apply in this case (though you could say _No, I don't have any kind of pen_).  I would understand _Don't you have any pens?_ to imply _Not even one or two?_ and _Don't you have pens?_ to imply something like _Don't you ever buy or use a pen?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to me to be at least two fifferent questions here.

I will answer the one which asks if "any" can be used with a singular noun. The answer to that is clearly "yes".

If someone asks "Do you have a good pen to write with?" i.e. a question about a specific type of pen, it is perfectly correct to answer: **"No, I don't have any pen"**. This means you have no pen at all.

It is also not incorrect to simply to say **"I need to write a note, but don't have any pen"**

It is effectively short for "any kind of (pen)".

It is also, of course, used with non-count nouns - as in "Do you have any money/bread/food/knowledge about flying saucers etc?""

A frequently used idiom involving "any" with a singular noun would be "Do you have **any idea** who is president of the Royal Society?""

Comment: Thank you, WS2. I Didn't ask more than one question so as not to 'clog' the forum feed. I'll take it into account next time.